# radius of convergence $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n! x^{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I just wondering **radius of convergence** following series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!  x^{n!}
\\
$$
My 1st attempt is 'root test'
$$
\sqrt[n!]{|a_{n!} |} =\sqrt[n!]{|n! |} =\sqrt[t]{t} \rightarrow 1
$$
So, I thoungt **radius of convergence** is '1'

*Is this right answer?*

$$
$$

$$
$$

And **2nd question!!**

My friend solve this problem wiht "ratio test"

He said

$$
|\frac{(n+1)!x^{(n+1)!}}{n!x^{n!}}| \le 1
\implies
|(n+1)x^{n \cdot n!}|\le1
\implies
|x|\le|\frac{1}{n+1}|^{\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}}
\rightarrow1
$$

So, **radius of convergence** is '1'

*Is this right answer?*

$$
$$
I've solved problem of this type through
$$
|\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_n x^n}|\le1
$$
So, I am uncertain for my friend's solution.

BECAUSE for the series, 
$$
a_2=0, a_3=0, a_k=0 
( k \not=n!)
$$

thus there will be
$$
\frac{0}{0}
$$

$$
$$

Please give me some advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, $R = 1$. Cauchy-Hadamard formula would also work. Just do the calculations thinking of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$

Comment: I modified 2nd question. Does C-H formula work well for case 0/0?

Comment: I don't think the *root test* that you demonstrated is correct. Also are you sure that the power of $x$ is $n!$?

Comment: "the power of x is n!".... umm.. SUM x^f(n) means 'the power of x is f(n)' isn't it?

Comment: @boywholived it is correct because $x^{(n+1)!}/x^{n!}=x^{(n+1)!-n!}=x^{n!(n+1-1)}=x^{n(n!)}$

Comment: Your friend's solution works. The key is to NOT apply the formula for the radius of convergence.  Rather, you apply the ratio or root test as if the series were NOT a power series, and then set $|L| < 1$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: @Paul Hurst // not a power series, but a series!! THANK you!! I've just known how the C-H 'formula' birth :-) THANKS a lot!! .

Comment: @ellya. The standard version of *root test* have the limit $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ rather than $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and I feel that  OP's proof does not imply convergence.

Comment: @boywholived, I see, sorry I thought you were commenting on the "friends answer"

Comment: @boywholived, In 'MY proof' '→1 (4th line)' means limit (a_n)^(1/n). So I think 'My proof' implies convergence. Thanks.

Comment: @user143993. The 4th line right now is $$\sqrt[n!]{|a_{n!} |} =\sqrt[n!]{|n! |}$$, you wrote $n!$ instead of $n$.

Comment: @boywholived,  Ahh,, You mean // In 'MY proof' '→1 (4th line)' means limit (a_n!)^(1/n!) INSTEAD OF (a_n)^(1/n), [if my reply above..] right?

Comment: @user143993. Yes

Comment: @boywholived, Cool! THANKS sincerely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The radius of convergence is $1$, since the sum converges for $x\in(-1,1)$, sometimes both approaches (ratio and root) will work, so it is fine that there are two methods.

Your uncertainty with $\frac{0}{0}$ is okay, because if we we had some series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$, and we knew for certain terms, where $x_n=0$, say for a set $S\subset\Bbb N$, then we would just rewrite the series as:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N\setminus S}x_n$, and we would assess the remaining sequence.

Example $x_n=1/n^2$ for $n$ odd, and $x_n=0$ for $n$ even, we would just have:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N\setminus 2\Bbb N}^\infty x_n$

Comment: Thanks for answer. You mean "reduce" the zero terms and regard as 'new' series, right?

Comment: Indeed, if you know beforehand that some terms are zero, then you wouldn't include them.

Comment: OK, I understand! THANK you very much. By the way, 1st solution (I did 'n! = t') is also right?

Comment: this is fine since both values change at the same rate, but I would keep it as $n!$ personally.

Comment: Sorry to bother you.. If keep it as n!, how can I calculate "lim{n!}^{1/n!}"? Could you give me some hint for calculating this limit?

Comment: just do $\lim_{n\to\infty}|n!|^{\frac{1}{n!}}=1$ (this result would be the same as if you put in $t$, but then to be precise, you would have to define the values $t$ takes, so it is simpler to keep is as $n!$)

Comment: "define the values t takes" Umm.. let me think this statement some minutes. THANK you very much!!!

Comment: what I mean is if you want to let $t\to \infty$, then you should specify that $t$ is taking the values $n!$, by the time you've done that there is no point! happy to help!

Comment: Ahh... If I take t=n!, then t=1=1! - (ok, at t=1) // but t=2=n! is impossible for any n in N, and so on..  // you mean this? right?

Comment: yes it is exactly that, so really there is no reason to make the substitution. :)

Comment: That's cool. You(and you guys) impressed me deeply. THANKS A LOT :-) .

Answer (score 4):

The power series here is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k
$$
where
$$
a_k=\left\{\begin{array}{}
k&\text{if $k=n!$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
where the non-zero terms are sparse. Several tests will fail because they reference consecutive terms (ratio test, alternating series, etc). The [Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) talks about
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}
$$
This test does not care about the behavior of consecutive terms, so it is well suited to this type of series. The formula to [determine the radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius)
$$
r=\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}}
$$
is based on the Root Test.

The [Comparison Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) also works to show that the series converges for $|x|\le1$ since for this series
$$
|a_k|\le k
$$
and the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$
converges for $|x|\lt1$.

The [Term Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) can also be used to show that the series does not converge for $|x|\ge1$.